# What types of glycosidic bonds are in oligosaccharides that occurs naturally not in the lab?

Tags: carbohydrates

An oligosaccharide is a carbohydrate formed by two or more monosaccharides.

If both monosaccharides are pyranose types, they can bond through ($\alpha$ or $\beta$)1-4 or ($\alpha$ or $\beta$)1-6. If one monosaccharide of them is of furanose type, they can bond through ($\alpha$ or $\beta$)1-2.

Examples:

[image]

or

[image]

- Is any other type of glycosidic bond type between monosaccharides in oligosaccharides that occurs naturally not in the lab?

Comment: If you have $n$ hydroxy groups on one sugar, you can form $4n$ glycosidic bonds with the anomeric centre of the other sugar. I’m willing to bet that examples can be found for almost each ‘variant’.